# Run two executables with system()

Tags: c++, executable, launch

I'm trying to write a small program that just runs two executables. Currently it only runs the first one for some reason:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

main(){

    cout << "Running Borderless Window..." << endl;
    system("BorderlessWindowed.exe");

    cout << "Running Diablo II MultiRes..." << endl;
    system("D2MultiResGame.exe.lnk");
}
```

It's just a small program to run Diablo II + a BorderlessWindow program.

Comment: it should probably read `int main()`...

Comment: `system` won't (normally) return until whatever program you tell it to execute exits. You could switch to `spawnvp` (or one of its cousins), or use `start` to execute the command and return immediately (among other possibilities).

Answer (score 3):

this will do the task

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

main(){

    cout << "Running Borderless Window... and Diablo II MultiRes" << endl;
    system("cmd /c start BorderlessWindowed.exe&&D2MultiResGame.exe.lnk");
    // this is what i have tried
    // system("cmd /c start notepad.exe&&mspaint.exe");
    // which starts notepad and mspaint one after another
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) It ran fine the first time, but the second it's still doing that my code did. Just runs BorderlessWindowed.exe and doesn't open the second.

Comment: @Archey ok... try the updated code. added concurrent application starting in windows. now this starts the two apps concurrently without waiting for other to complete

Comment: @Archey were you able to test this ?

Answer (score 1):

Alright since `system()` requires that the first process be done with before it launched the second I just created a batch file that starts both, and had the .exe launch the batch file.