# run the same exe with different argument simultaneous in c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, batch-file

Does anyone have idea to open same exe file with different arguments at same time in c++.
In the past, I always open multiple commend line in windows to run the exe simultaneously,
However, it seems not a best way to solve it.                                                                  Hence I try implement it in c++ to automatically run the multiple processing at same time.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11464665/2469488), but it still can not work....
my problem:
e.g. run
1. a.exe -dir D: -num 1000
2. a.exe -dir D: -num 1500
3. a.exe -dir D: -num 2500
at same time in c++.

Comment: Since it seems you're on Windows you might want to read about [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: instead of taking the arguments from command line. generate the desired test cases within the same program and input them while your exe is in run. otherwise there is not such way i have seen so far.

Comment: You can ceate an icon for a batch file and use cmd/C in it.  Not sure what you're asking..

Comment: Use `system("start start_options_go_here a.exe ...")` - you will need to look up the help for start command to figure out what you want as "options go here".

Comment: `cmd.exe /C` is the way to do it with `_spawnve` this way you will open all the exe's inside the same console (your actual program) pretty much all the exe's will be part of the same program that ran them. (you can still kill them off 1 by 1 on Task manager.) you will see their outputs inside your main console program. Yes there is no way to close them (unless they close themselves).

Comment: The trivial answer is: CreateProcess. The question (now) contains code that does this. So your question (now) is?

Comment: I already solve it :), so I just share my solution!!

Comment: Do you want to use a batch file or a C++ program?

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in edits. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OPs Solution is:

> Sol:

```
std::ostringstream trainsamplesCmd[2];
trainsamplesCmd[0] << "a.exe -data cascade/1 -vec vec/test.vec -bg neg.txt -numPos 1000 -numNeg 1000 -w 30 -h 14";
trainsamplesCmd[1] << "a.exe -data cascade/2 -vec vec/test.vec -bg neg.txt -numPos 1500 -numNeg 1000 -w 30 -h 14";
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        const_cast<char *>(trainsamplesCmd[i].str().c_str()),        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```